# Laravel - electron js, build the project

Tags: php, electron

I have electron js project with laravel application, here is the structure of the project:

```
laravel
php 
main.js
package.json
```

**Note** : I use `node-php-server`package to run laravel application with electron.

When I run `npm run start` everything is good, however when I try to build the project using `electron-builder`, I get this error message (when I try to open exe file):

```
Error : spawn
C:\........\php\php.exe
```

Also when I change the name of laravel dir to www, I get this error message:

```
There is no entry file in package.json
```

I also used  `electron-packager` & `electron forge` and both of them got stuck without any error message!

This is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "###",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "license": "MIT",
  "description": "your app description",
  "author": "####",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "install-app-deps",
    "start": "electron .",
    "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
    "dist": "electron-builder",
    "build": "electron-packager . LaravelElectron --out=dist --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --asar"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "yourappid",
    "dmg": {
      "contents": [
        {
          "x": 110,
          "y": 150
        },
        {
          "x": 240,
          "y": 150,
          "type": "link",
          "path": "/Applications"
        }
      ]
    },
    "linux": {
      "target": [
        "AppImage",
        "deb"
      ]
    },
    "win": {
      "target": "NSIS",
      "icon": "build/icon.ico"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-builder-squirrel-windows": "^20.32.0",
    "node-php-server": "latest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "latest",
    "electron-builder": "latest",
    "electron-packager": "^15.4.0"
  }
}
```